# How to create a new item in a list while updating a item?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I want to create new item with metadata when existing item is updated .

how to achieve this task.

If any existing item get updated

- Delete current item
- Created new item with metadata

Comment: then what's the use of updating an item, you can directly insert the item in a list.

Comment: item has more than 50 fields, dont want to create again but copy item with some adjustment

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an event receiver on item updated to add to the new list as the following :

```
 public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);


             using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://epm/workflow"))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                            {
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                SPList DList = web.Lists.TryGetList("destlist");
                                SPListItem newItem = DList.Items.Add();
                             // list your fields in a Destination list with  your value
                                newItem["fieldname"] = properties.AfterProperties["fieldname"].ToString(); // or properties.ListItem["fieldname"];
                                newItem.Update();
                              }                                     

                     }  
                }
```

Comment: Hi Qassas, if i am using AfterProperties["fieldname"], updated value only comes, not getting previous version value. Tried with BeforeProperties and faces null value exception

Comment: Hi @samdaniel  if you want to get both the old and new values, you have to use ItemUpdating event receiver and use properties.ListItem to get old values and properties.AfterProperties to get the new ones. but based on your question you need the new value on itepUpdate, no problem you need just now to copy this code at ItemUpdating and check , please don't hesitate to tell me if you need any clarification